# jquery form type="file" how to tell when a file has been selected?

Tags: jquery, scripting

When a user selects a file, I want another file field to appear. It works for the first file, but if i choose a file in the second field, it doesn't get called again. Why not?

jquery script

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var i = 1;

        $('input:file[name$=\'uploadedFile'+(i-1)+'\']').change(function() {
            var file = $(this).val();

            if(file !== null && file !== "") {
                $(this).after("<input type=\"file\" name=\"uploadededFile"+i+"\" />");
                i++;
            }
        });
    });
```

html form

```
<form action="PHP/file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="500000" />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedFile0" />
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me figure that out :) Just needed this after 1 item was uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `$(...).change(function)`, you are adding the handler to the elements that are *currently* in the jQuery object.  When you add a new `<input>`, it doesn;t have any event handlers.

You need to call [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), which will handle the event for all matching elements, no matter when they were created.
For example:

```
$('input:file:last').live('change', function() { ... });
```

Note that the selector is only evaluated once, so it won't pick up changes in `i`.
Instead, you should use `:last`.

Comment: Ok that worked. It only worked once i used input:file:last...plus it's a much simpler solution. Thank you.

Comment: JUST FYI - live has been removed as of jQuery 1.9, so use .on() instead. It's also much easier to keep an element bound using .on() than .live(). SEE : http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

Since this code only runs when your page is loaded, your onchange handler only applies to an input element with the name `uploadedFile0`. You need to extend your event handler to create a new element **and** bind the appropriate event handling function to it.